# Getting PCM data from wavesurfer.js backend/web audio api

Tags: javascript, wav, web-audio-api, pcm, wavesurfer.js

I am using wavesurfer.js to create a multitrack player online and want to export a remixed version of the combined tracks with levels panning etc.

First I have an array of audioFiles and use this to create an array of wavesurfer elements.

```
for(var i=0; i<audiofiles.length; i++){
    spectrum[i] = WaveSurfer.create({
        
    });
}
```

I then create a buffer for each of these from wavesurfer backend

```
for(var i=0; i<audiofiles.length; i++){
    
    var ctx = spectrum[i].backend.ac;
    var length = spectrum[i].getDuration() * sample_rate * 2;
    var ctx_buffer = ctx.createBuffer(2, length, ctx.sampleRate);

    // pass raw pcm buffer to download function
}
```

And then finally I got some help with the download function here [Downloading audio from web that has been modified with wavesurfer.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157122/downloading-audio-from-web-that-has-been-modified-with-wavesurfer-js)

My issue at this point is that what I'm passing to the download function doesn't seem to be in the correct format. I'm new to working with Audio and not sure what I'm doing.

If I pass the ctx_buffer variable to the function in the other question (and use it instead of the buffer variable there which is got directly from a pcm file) I will get a successful download but the file is empty, although it is the correct length (leaving out the *2 in the length above will have an empty file exactly half the length of my original).

There is an exportPCM() function in wavesurfer.js here https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/methods.html but I'm not sure how this works either.

### Edit

```
buttons.save_all.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("download_icon").className = "fas fa-spinner loader";
    document.getElementById("download_text").innerText = "Loading...";
    
    var length = spectrum[0].getDuration()*44100*2;
    for(var i=0; i<audiofiles.length; i++){
        var ctx = spectrum[i].backend.ac;
        var sample_rate = ctx.sampleRate;
        var length = spectrum[i].getDuration()*sample_rate*2;
        
        var ctx_buffer = ctx.createBuffer(2, length, ctx.sampleRate);

        download_init(ctx_buffer,length,sample_rate).catch(showError);
    }
}, false);

function showError(e) {
    console.log(`ERROR: ${e}`);
}

var x = 0;
async function download_init(ctx_buffer,length,sample_rate) {
    // const buffer = await (await fetch(url)).arrayBuffer()
    
    const wavBytes = getWavBytes(ctx_buffer, {
        numFrames: ctx_buffer.length,
        numChannels: 1,
        sampleRate: sample_rate,
        isFloat: false
    });
    console.log(wavBytes);
    
    blobs[x] = URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([wavBytes], { type: 'audio/wav' })
    )
    
    document.getElementById("btn_download").href = blobs[0];
    document.getElementById("btn_download").setAttribute('download', 'download.wav');
    
    document.getElementById("btn_save_all").hidden = true;
    document.getElementById("btn_download").hidden = false;
    
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Hi Paddy. Are you able to get a "combined" variable/object that contains the mixed audio in its entirety that you wish to export?  If so, what type of object is this (`AudioBuffer`, `Float32Array`, etc)?  Or is all the final, mixed audio split across an array? And what object type are you passing to the download function?

Comment: At the moment i'm just trying to get one track of the multitrack to download and I can try combine them afterwards, so at the moment it is just an array of audiobuffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you currently have an array of `AudioBuffer` objects, you can interleave the Float32Array PCM data contained within each `AudioBuffer`, and then use that interleaved PCM to create a RIFF/Wav file to download.  If each `AudioBuffer` is a track, then all of the left/right channels in the array must be combined separately and interleaved at the end.  Here's how to start with one `AudioBuffer` track:

[Convert AudioBuffer to ArrayBuffer / Blob for WAV Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172398/convert-audiobuffer-to-arraybuffer-blob-for-wav-download)

Comment: thanks for your help with this i'm new to working with audio so i'm getting totally lost at the moment and it's not helping that i've another library to draw the waveforms, i've added the code i had before to kind of give you an understanding of what i'm trying to do

Comment: Ha, no problem at all.  I was lost when I started too but don't worry we'll figure this out! Feel free to contact me directly too if that's easier than going back/forth here.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution from the question author to move it to the answer section)*.

Final code thanks to @AnthumChris:

```
buttons.save_all.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("download_icon").className = "fas fa-spinner loader";
    document.getElementById("download_text").innerText = "Loading...";
    for (let i=0; i<audiofiles.length; i++) {
        const track = spectrum[i];
        const sampleRate = track.backend.ac.sampleRate;
        const audioBuffer = track.backend.buffer;
        const interleavedSamples = getInterleavedStereo(audioBuffer);
        const file_name = `track-${i+1}.wav`;
        download_init(interleavedSamples.buffer, sampleRate, file_name);
    }
    console.log(blobs);
}, false);

function showError(e) {
    console.log(`ERROR: ${e}`);
}

var x = 0;
function download_init(ctx_buffer, sample_rate, file_name) {
    const wavBytes = getWavBytes(ctx_buffer, {
        numChannels: 2,
        sampleRate: sample_rate,
        isFloat: true
    });
    blobs[x] = URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([wavBytes], { type: 'audio/wav' })
    )
    buttons.download.href = blobs[0];
    buttons.download.setAttribute('download', file_name);
    buttons.save_all.hidden = true;
    buttons.download.hidden = false;
    x++;
}

function getInterleavedStereo(audioBuffer) {
    if (audioBuffer.numberOfChannels !== 2) {
        throw Error('source audio is not stereo');
    }
    const [left, right] = [audioBuffer.getChannelData(0), audioBuffer.getChannelData(1)];
    const interleaved = new Float32Array(left.length + right.length);
    for (let src=0, dst=0; src < left.length; src++, dst+=2) {
      interleaved[dst] =   left[src];
      interleaved[dst+1] = right[src];
    }
    return interleaved;
}

function getWavBytes(buffer, options) {
    const type = options.isFloat ? Float32Array : Uint16Array;
    const numFrames = buffer.byteLength / type.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    const headerBytes = getWavHeader(Object.assign({}, options, { numFrames }));
    const wavBytes = new Uint8Array(headerBytes.length + buffer.byteLength);
    wavBytes.set(headerBytes, 0);
    wavBytes.set(new Uint8Array(buffer), headerBytes.length);
    return wavBytes;
}

function getWavHeader(options) {
    const numFrames = options.numFrames;
    const numChannels = options.numChannels || 2;
    const sampleRate = options.sampleRate || 44100;
    const bytesPerSample = options.isFloat? 4 : 2;
    const format = options.isFloat? 3 : 1;
    const blockAlign = numChannels * bytesPerSample;
    const byteRate = sampleRate * blockAlign;
    const dataSize = numFrames * blockAlign;
    const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44);
    const dv = new DataView(buffer);

    let p = 0;
    function writeString(s) {
        for (let i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
            dv.setUint8(p + i, s.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        p += s.length;
    }
    function writeUint32(d) {
        dv.setUint32(p, d, true);
        p += 4;
    }
    function writeUint16(d) {
        dv.setUint16(p, d, true);
        p += 2;
    }

    writeString('RIFF');                // ChunkID
    writeUint32(dataSize + 36);         // ChunkSize
    writeString('WAVE');                // Format
    writeString('fmt ');                // Subchunk1ID
    writeUint32(16);                    // Subchunk1Size
    writeUint16(format);                // AudioFormat
    writeUint16(numChannels);           // NumChannels
    writeUint32(sampleRate);            // SampleRate
    writeUint32(byteRate);              // ByteRate
    writeUint16(blockAlign);            // BlockAlign
    writeUint16(bytesPerSample * 8);    // BitsPerSample
    writeString('data');                // Subchunk2ID
    writeUint32(dataSize);              // Subchunk2Size

    return new Uint8Array(buffer);
}
```